# Run Query on Dynamics CRM from Sharepoint Page using ODATA in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, odata, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to query CRM from a SharePoint page. I use this to get the user's full name:

```
ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
web.get_currentUser();
```

This would give me "Surname, Forename", then I use a substring function change this to "Forename Surname"

I then create an ODATA query to get the SystemUserId from CRM, using:

```
#CRM_URL#/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet?$top=50&$select=SystemUserId&$filter=FullName eq '" + userFullName + "'"
```

The URL returns the FullName field, when run as a query it runs without an error, but I am only given the FullName in the results, I want to get the SystemUserId.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: The above query is returning SystemUserId in my browser test & Restbuilder test.. how are you getting FullName instead?

Comment: can you add the screenshot/output of what you are getting in result/response?

Comment: You are correct, it worked after I shutdown the PC out and came back a few days later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It worked after a restart, not sure why.